# How to provide filters with "And" and "Or" condition for each column in DataTable Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a grid. I want to provide filter for each column. I have done that with https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Above filter provides filter with "And" condition between 2 column.

I want to set filter with "Or" condition for 2 columns.

Can any body please guide me for this?

Comment: Could you share us your code?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the link you provided.  Click on the comments tab and scroll halfway down to the code supplied by **vbrouchet**.

Comment: @SebastienD I have added link and use same code for JS/CSS/HTML provided under table in link. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment, the answer you need is in the link you provided under the comments tab (user **vbrouchet**).  Since this isn't my code, I haven't verified or tested it.  I'm merely posting it here as a convenience.  Hopefully this solution is what you're after.

**Note:** I slightly expanded on their code to also handle for `cut`, `copy` and `paste` actions as well.

```
var mytable = $('#example').DataTable();

mytable.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
    $('input', mytable.column(colIdx).footer()).on('keyup change copy paste cut', function () {
        mytable.column (colIdx)
                 .search (this.value.replace(/;/g, &quot;|&quot;), true, false)
                 .draw ();
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I think it apply "OR" filter for particular column. i.e `abc;xyz` if you write this keyword in name column than it will list user whose name contains "abc" or "xyz". This filter is "OR" for same column. I want filter "OR" between all column. If user put "abc" in name column and "New York" in city column, all the records should display whose name is abc or city is New York(regardless of name"